# How to send patches in .net to client

Tags: asp.net, deployment

We have n-tier asp.net app with approx 200 pages and 400 classes spanned over many dlls . When we want to send patch (single .aspx page changed) we have to compile it as a solution and deployed for QA testing. Once QA tested, we need to send the patch to client where we face problem. Now, we need send the entire published folder which includes many code that are not part of changes.

Is there any better way of handling this? We should be able to send only file that changed or related files only but the problem is how to identify what all changed once published.

Comment: TFS should be able to compute the diff. Your nightly builds should produce everything you need. Archive the official release versions, then check to see which dlls have changed since last time, and only replace those. This is a partial solution, but perhaps a good start.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar discussion on MSDN [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/9cbb06da-a9c2-4a06-abdd-573b52ccecb6) with solutions.